Почему отрицательные числа обрабатываются после положительных?
По-идее отрицательные числа должны находиться левее в числовом ряду, а учитывая, что объект обрабатывает значения от меньшего к большему, следовательно, они должны быть меньше и обрабатываться раньше, но в данном случае обрабатываются в самом конце, почему?
console.log("Ты целочисленное?", String(Math.trunc(Number("-1"))) === "-1");
//true

в примере выше видно, что js обрабатывает -1 как целочисленное;
а вот сам код:
let obj = { 
name: "John",

age: 30,
9: "it's number",
0: "it's string",
"-1": "it's fraction",
};

for (let i in obj) {
console.log(`${i}: ${obj[i]}`);
}

/*0: it's string
9: it's number
name: John
age: 30
-1: it's fraction*/


The traversal order, as of modern ECMAScript specification, is well-defined and consistent across implementations. Within each component of the prototype chain, all non-negative integer keys (those that can be array indices) will be traversed first in ascending order by value, then other string keys in ascending chronological order of property creation.

for..in спецификация
